# View filters vs Content Grouping, Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, what is the difference between creating several Views each with its own Filter vs creating one View with Content Groupings? And then what's up with Custom Dimensions?

I know there's a lot of information about these topics out there but nothing comparing them all. They all seem like the same to me.

So for example, say I want to add tracking to a Web Component that I made that will be included in many people's sites (different top level domains). I could make a different view+filter for each top level domain I expected someone to use my Web Component on, or I could make a content grouping that splits on the top level domain.

Answer (score 1):

One big difference is the number you are allowed to create.   There is a limit if 25 views per property, but there is no limit on the number of content groupings you can create.

Another difference is that filters discard data.   So if you filter out everything other than a section of your site, you can't view that section of your site in relationship to other sections.   For example you might want to see users that viewed the content group "women's clothing" and then see how they performed at checkout.  If you filtered out everything except "women's clothing", you wouldn't be able to view the checkout data in that view.

Content groupings also allow you to view more than one group at once.   You could view the stats for "men's clothing" and "boy's clothing" together.  Separate views cannot be combined.